# how to show datepicker on button click?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am using date picker of ** angular bootstap** .I want to show datepicker on click of button ..But my datepicker is display when i run my plunker .How to show the date picker on button click .If user select any date .It should display on button text ? how I set the button text as a selected date..
here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/dTaCRAzS7t21uKL2MQBF?p=preview

I am using this 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

```
<body ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller='cntrl'>
      {{3+4}}
      <button ng-click='openDate()'>{{open_date_picker}}</button>
      <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
      <uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></uib-datepicker>
    </div>

    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to fix the issue

HTML

```
  <button ng-click='showDate=true'>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</button>
  <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
  <uib-datepicker ng-show="showDate" ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" 
  show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" 
  custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></uib-datepicker>
```

JS Controller Code

```
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap']).controller('cntrl',function($scope){
  $scope.dt = "opendate";
})
```

This code only shows the date when button is clicked. You cannot hide once the button is clicked. To hide the calendar just set `showDate=false` whenever you want.

Here is the Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/1ZYTUvMPoTOG4L09j34N?p=preview which toggles the date control on click of button and updated the button text to selected date. Just format the date however it is required.